# Do I need to build a custom page to list nodes by content type?

Tags: 7, nodes

## Environment

- Mac OSX 10.8.2
- MAMP
- Drupal 7 (just downloaded the stable today)

## Objective

Create a menu item in the main menu to list **recent** and **all** nodes of a specific content type.

## Question

It appears that I'm going to need to build a custom page, and leverage an API, to simply list nodes by content type. I just know I'm missing something. Can somebody point me in the right direction on how to do this?

I ran this Google searche, [drupal 7 list nodes of content type](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&newwindow=1&safe=active&tbo=d&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=drupal+7+list+nodes+of+content+type&oq=drupal+7+list+nodes+of+content+type&gs_l=hp.3..0i30.1195.1195.0.1673.1.1.0.0.0.0.79.79.1.1.0.les;..0.0...1c.2.3.psy-ab.UCNunEjlRCg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42553238,d.dmQ&fp=70853370b4ccefac&biw=1291&bih=835), to come to the conclusion that I'm going to need to build some kind of custom code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to build a custom page.  What you want to do is very simple to do with the *Views* module.

Just build a View to list nodes, and under `Filter criteria`, add a filter that only displays nodes of whatever content type you want to single out.

Comment: Outstanding! And it appears that will be part of core in v8. I have used a lot of CMS systems, and I do mean a lot, across PHP and ASP.NET and I have to say I *love* Drupal already! And I haven't even been using it that long (just a few hours).